# Compile program for 32bit on 64bit Linux OS causes fatal error

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu

Using

```
gcc -m32 myprog.c
```

should compile in 32 bit version the file `myprog.c`.

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:27:0,
                 from myprog.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:374:25: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
#include <sys/cdefs.h>
```

How could I fix this?

If I don't use `-m32` it works but uses 64 bit instructions.

Comment: And the program compiles fine if you remove the `-m32` flag?

Comment: hope http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/High-Level-Synthesis-HLS/Vivado-HLS-cdefs-h-No-such-file-or-directory/td-p/324969 helps

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes if I remove -m32 works, but compile using 64 bit istructions

Comment: You need to install the 32-bit development libraries and headers (the package is usually named ia32-libs-dev or something similar).

Comment: Is it possible you need to install some 32-bit compiler package which includes the proper headers? edit: @JoachimPileborg beat me to it!

Comment: Is the first thing that I have thought but, what exactly I need to install? (I need only to compile simple c methods using 32 bit instructions)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

To compile 32 bit binaries on 64 bit Linux version, you have to Install `libx32gcc` development package and 32 bit GNU C Library

try this

```
sudo apt-get install libx32gcc-4.8-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
```

Comment: Thanks, BTW libc6-dev-i386 will install libx32gcc as dependency so no need to install it manually :D

Comment: libx32gcc is NOT the same as lib32gcc. libx32gcc is dependent on extensions found on x86_64 CPU's operating in 32-bit mode. It will fail if you're targeting true 32-bit only intel cpu's

Comment: Dear, Trying to compile wine32, I confronted the same problem. Of Great help was that tip [CODE]"./configure --libdir=/usr/local/lib32"[/CODE] from here https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew/issues/142

Answer (score 13):

You need gcc multilib support. Install the package `gcc-multilib`. E.g.:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered to this same problem. when I was trying to build 32 bit so file while i'm in 64 bit ubuntu version.

you can build by switching your lib version into 64 bit
in netbeans
*(-> **project properties** -> **C compiler** -> **additional options**)* set to

```
-shared -m64
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue we first need to know which package will provide the file **sys/cdefs.h**

In CentOs/RHEL based system you can find it by running below command

```
yum provides '*sys/cdefs.h'
```

Similarly, in Debian/Ubuntu systems you can find it by running

```
apt-file search 'sys/cdefs.h'
```

*Note:* If apt-file package is not already present on the system install it with command

```
apt-get install apt-file
```

Both above commands will scan the respective package management systems database i.e RPM/Apt and tells the name of the package which supplies the file ending with "sys/cdefs.h".

Install the appropriate package from the packages listed by the commands.
Like

**On CentOs/RHEL**:

```
yum install glibc-headers
```

On Debian/Ubuntu

```
apt-get install libc6-dev
```

This approach is not only useful for this particular issue but any similar issue which is reporting some required file being provided by some package being not present.