# How to compile Knuth's program's?

Tags: c, literate-programming

I am trying to compile one of Donald Knuth's programs http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/programs/grayspan.w.

I am using Ubuntu, I installed  Marc van Leeuwen's version of CWEB which uses ctanglex and cweavex, I also installed the Stanford Graphbase.
At the commandline I type; `ctanglex grayspan.w`

This produces a file; grayspan.c
However when I compile (`gcc grayspan.c -o grayspan`)
I get this error

```
grayspan.c:1:23: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘>’ token  
#define verbose (argc>2)
```

The output of the command `ctanglex grayspan.w` is;

```
ctanglex grayspan.w
This is CTANGLE (Version x3.04)
*1
! `@f', `@d', `@h', and `@c' are ignored in section body. (l. 32)
@h
  *4*6*16*18
Writing the output file (grayspan.c):..
Done.
(Pardon me, but I think I spotted something wrong)
```

and the full output of `gcc grayspan.c -o grayspan` is;

```
grayspan.c:1:22: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘>’ token
 #define verbose (argc>2)
                      ^
grayspan.w: In function ‘print_arcs’:
grayspan.w:125:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf(" %d (to %s)\n",a->len,a->tip->name);
 ^
grayspan.w: In function ‘print_a’:
grayspan.w:348:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
        k,aa(k)->len, aa(k)->tip->name, mate(aa(k))->tip->name);
 ^
grayspan.w: In function ‘main’:
grayspan.w:55:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     argv[1],panic_code);
 ^
grayspan.w:233:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     l,e->len,v->name,v->deg);
 ^
grayspan.w:233:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
grayspan.w:205:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     for (k=1;k<n;k++) printf(" %d",aa(k)->len);
 ^
grayspan.w:206:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     if (extraverbose && change_e) printf(" (-%d+%d)\n",change_e->len,e->len);
 ^
grayspan.w:206:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
grayspan.w:208:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
   }@+else printf("%.15g: -%d+%d\n",count,change_e->len,e->len);
 ^
grayspan.w:208:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
grayspan.w:254:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     l,e->len,v->name,v->deg);
 ^
grayspan.w:254:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
grayspan.w:272:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     l,e->len,u->name);
 ^
grayspan.w:277:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     l,e->len,e->link->len!=e->len? e->link->len: e->link->link->len);
 ^
grayspan.w:277:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
grayspan.w:288:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
 if (extraverbose) printf("level %d: %d is a bridge\n",l,e->len);
 ^
grayspan.w:302:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
 if (extraverbose) printf("level %d: deleting %d\n",l,e->len);
 ^
grayspan.w:310:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
   if (extraverbose) printf("undeleting %d\n",e->len);'
```

The file grayspan.c ;
for all those who wont click on an external link;

```
#define verbose (argc>2)
#define extraverbose (argc>3)
#define o mems++
#define oo mems+=2
#define ooo mems+=3
#define oooo mems+=4
#define ooooo mems+=5
#define deg u.I
#define prev a.A
#define mate(e)(edge_trick&(siz_t)(e)?(e)-1:(e)+1)
#define aa(l)(g->vertices+l)->z.A
#define del(l)(g->vertices+l)->y.A
#define link b.A
#define delete(e)ee=e,oooo,ee->prev->next=ee->next,ee->next->prev=ee->prev
#define undelete(e)ee=e,oooo,ee->next->prev=ee,ee->prev->next=ee
#define bfs v.V
#define sentinel (g->vertices)
/*1:*/
#line 30 "grayspan.w"
#include "gb_graph.h"
#include "gb_save.h"

double mems;
double count;/*5:*/
#line 120 "grayspan.w"
void print_arcs(Vertex*v)
{
register Arc*a;
printf("Arcs leading from %s:\n",v->name);
for(a=v->arcs->next;a->tip;a=a->next)
printf(" %d (to %s)\n",a->len,a->tip->name);
}/*:5*//*17:*/
#line 343 "grayspan.w"
void print_a(register Graph*g)
{
register int k;
for(k=1;k<g->n;k++)
printf(" a%d=%d (%s -- %s)\n",
k,aa(k)->len,aa(k)->tip->name,mate(aa(k))->tip->name);
}/*:17*/
#line 35 "grayspan.w"

main(int argc,char*argv[])
{/*3:*/
#line 62 "grayspan.w"
register Graph*g;
register int n;
register int k;
register Vertex*u,*v,*w;
register Arc*e,*ee,*f,*ff;/*:3*//*8:*/
#line 197 "grayspan.w"
register int l;
Arc*change_e;/*:8*/
#line 38 "grayspan.w"
;/*2:*/
#line 47 "grayspan.w"
if(argc<2){
fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s foo.gb [[gory] details]\n",argv[0]);
exit(1);
}
g=restore_graph(argv[1]);
if(!g){
fprintf(stderr,
"Sorry, can't create the graph from file %s! (error code %d)\n",
argv[1],panic_code);
exit(-1);
}
n=g->n;/*4:*/
#line 89 "grayspan.w"
if(verbose)printf("Graph %s has the following edges:\n",g->id);
for(v=g->vertices,k=0;v<g->vertices+n;v++){
f=gb_virgin_arc();f->next=v->arcs;
for(v->deg=0,e=v->arcs,v->arcs=f;e;v->deg++,f=e,e=e->next){
e->prev=f;
u=e->tip;
if(u==v){
fprintf(stderr,"Oops, there's a loop from %s to itself!\n",v->name);
exit(-3);
}
if(mate(e)->tip!=v){
fprintf(stderr,"Oops: There's an arc from %s to %s,\n",u->name,v->name);
fprintf(stderr," but the edge trick doesn't find the opposite arc!\n");
exit(-4);
}
if(u>v){
e->len=mate(e)->len= ++k;
if(verbose)printf(" %d: %s -- %s\n",k,v->name,u->name);
}
}
v->arcs->prev=f,f->next=v->arcs;
if(v->deg==0){
fprintf(stderr,"Graph %s has an isolated vertex %s!\n",
g->id,v->name);
exit(-5);
}
}/*:4*/
#line 59 "grayspan.w"
;/*:2*/
#line 39 "grayspan.w"
;/*16:*/
#line 322 "grayspan.w"
for(v=g->vertices+1;v<g->vertices+n;v++)v->bfs=NULL;
for(k=n-1,o,w=v=g->vertices,w->bfs=sentinel;;o,v=w,w=w->bfs){
for(oo,e=v->arcs->next;o,u=e->tip;o,e=e->next)
if(o,u->bfs==NULL){
o,aa(k)=e,k--;
if(k==0)goto connected;
o,u->bfs=w,w=u;
}
if(w==sentinel)break;
}
printf("Oops, the graph isn't connected!\n");exit(0);
connected:for(u=g->vertices;u<g->vertices+n;u++)o,u->bfs=NULL;
if(extraverbose){
printf("Depth-first search yields the following spanning tree:\n");
print_a(g);
}
if(verbose)printf("(%.15g mems for initialization)\n",mems);/*:16*/
#line 40 "grayspan.w"
;/*7:*/
#line 175 "grayspan.w"
change_e=NULL;
v=g->vertices;
for(l=1;l<n-1;l++){
o,del(l)=NULL;
enter:ooo,e=aa(l+1),u=e->tip,v=mate(e)->tip;
if(oo,u->deg>v->deg)v=u,e=mate(e),u=e->tip;/*10:*/
#line 226 "grayspan.w"
oo,k=u->deg+v->deg;
for(o,f=u->arcs->next,ff=NULL;o,f->tip;o,f=f->next)
if(f->tip==v)delete(f),delete(mate(f)),k-=2,o,f->link=ff,ff=f;
else o,mate(f)->tip=v;
oo,e->link=ff,v->deg=k;
if(extraverbose)
printf("level %d: Shrinking %d; now %s has degree %d\n",
l,e->len,v->name,v->deg);
o,ff=v->arcs;
oooo,f->prev->next=ff->next,ff->next->prev=f->prev;
ooo,f->next->prev=ff,ff->next=f->next;/*:10*/
#line 181 "grayspan.w"
;
o,aa(l)=e;
}
for(o,e=v->arcs->next;o,e->tip;o,e=e->next){
o,aa(l)=e;/*9:*/
#line 201 "grayspan.w"
count++;
if(verbose){
if(!change_e||extraverbose){
printf("%.15g:",count);
for(k=1;k<n;k++)printf(" %d",aa(k)->len);
if(extraverbose&&change_e)printf(" (-%d+%d)\n",change_e->len,e->len);
else printf("\n");
}else printf("%.15g: -%d+%d\n",count,change_e->len,e->len);
}/*:9*/
#line 186 "grayspan.w"
;
change_e=e;
}
for(l--;l;l--){
e=aa(l),u=e->tip,v=mate(e)->tip;/*11:*/
#line 245 "grayspan.w"
oo,f=u->arcs,ff=v->arcs;
ooo,ff->next=f->prev->next;o,ff->next->prev=ff;
ooo,f->prev->next=f,f->next->prev=f;
for(f=f->prev;o,f->tip;o,f=f->prev)o,mate(f)->tip=u;
for(oo,f=e->link,k=v->deg;f;o,f=f->link)
k+=2,undelete(mate(f)),undelete(f);
oo,v->deg=k-u->deg;
if(extraverbose)
printf("level %d: Unshrinking %d; now %s has degree %d\n",
l,e->len,v->name,v->deg);/*:11*/
#line 191 "grayspan.w"
;/*12:*/
#line 270 "grayspan.w"
if(o,u->deg==1){
if(extraverbose)printf("level %d: %d is a bridge with endpoint %s\n",
l,e->len,u->name);
goto bridge;
}
if(o,e->link->link){
if(extraverbose)printf("level %d: %d is parallel to %d\n",
l,e->len,e->link->len!=e->len?e->link->len:e->link->link->len);
goto nonbridge;
}
for(o,u->bfs=v,w=u;u!=v;o,u=u->bfs){
for(oo,f=u->arcs->next;o,f->tip;o,f=f->next)
if(o,f->tip->bfs==NULL){
if(f->tip==v){
if(f!=mate(e))/*13:*/
#line 296 "grayspan.w"
{
for(o,u=e->tip;u!=v;o,u->bfs=NULL,u=w)o,w=u->bfs;
goto nonbridge;
}/*:13*/
#line 284 "grayspan.w"
;
}else oo,f->tip->bfs=v,w->bfs=f->tip,w=f->tip;
}
}
if(extraverbose)printf("level %d: %d is a bridge\n",l,e->len);
for(o,u=e->tip;u!=v;o,u->bfs=NULL,u=w)o,w=u->bfs;
goto bridge;
nonbridge:change_e=e;/*14:*/
#line 302 "grayspan.w"
if(extraverbose)printf("level %d: deleting %d\n",l,e->len);
ooo,e->link=del(l),del(l)=e;
delete(e),delete(mate(e)),oo,e->tip->deg--,v->deg--;
goto enter;/*:14*/
#line 292 "grayspan.w"
;
bridge:/*:12*/
#line 192 "grayspan.w"
;/*15:*/
#line 308 "grayspan.w"
for(o,e=del(l);e;o,e=e->link){
oooo,mate(e)->tip->deg++,e->tip->deg++,undelete(mate(e)),undelete(e);
if(extraverbose)printf("undeleting %d\n",e->len);
}/*:15*/
#line 193 "grayspan.w"
;
}/*:7*/
#line 41 "grayspan.w"
;
printf("Altogether %.15g spanning trees, using %.15g mems.\n",count,mems);
exit(0);
}/*:1*/
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that `#define`. So the issue has to be later in the code when the define is actually used.

Comment: please post the actual contents of `grayspan.c`.   Then we can relate the warning messages to the actual c code.   One thing to keep in mind is that the 'knuth' products are several decades old and modern c compilers are a lot smarter than they were back then.

Comment: grayspan.c has been uploaded to http://www.squaring.net/polygons/grayspan.c

Comment: And you expect to open an unknown external link? Edit your question's and add a [mcve]!

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the question.  This is Donald Knuth's program, not mine.  The program is a complete piece of work, I am not sure how I would minimise it.  The 'external link' is to a text file, ascii code, like html - pretty harmless!

Comment: given this warning as an example: "grayspan.w:55:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     argv[1],panic_code);"  `panic_code` is a 'long int' so the forth parameter in the associated statement: `  fprintf(stderr,
    "Sorry, can't create the graph from file %s! (error code %d)\n",
    argv[1],panic_code);`  should be `%ld` rather than `%d`   Most of the other warning messages are of a similar nature.   Suggest fix all those simple warnings, then add the updated code to the question.

Comment: I just spent the last 2+ hours going through the .w and .c files.  There are LOTS of syntax problems and poor programming practices exhibited in those files.  Suggest comment out all the `#line` statements so the error/warnings are directed toward the .c file, then fix all those warnings.

Comment: our friend Knuth, is a very very good source for algorithms.  However, as you have found out, not so good for actual code.  The C language has massively changed since back when Knuth was writing pseudo code and converters to change that pseudo code to any of several different languages

Comment: @user3629249 Not so much of a substance had changed in the C language. Knuth's programs are a little bit bit-rotten (less than one would expect for programs of that age) but otherwise quite workable. See my answer.

Comment: For posterity, here is a short guide I wrote while trying to figure out how to run Don's programs, as someone who is rather computer-illiterate. Hope it helps someone: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZRgDA6G0e9RHAOeUG8Ldy2hGIlZccQy5QTiJ_Jf-8ME/

Answer (score 2):

First, you will need the Stanford graph base (http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/sgb/sgb.tar.gz) and `ctangle` (part of Tex Live package on most Linux distros) installed.

Unzipping the SGB and running `make tests` in its directory will produce the necessary include and source files (should work out of the box on any decent Linux).

Put `grayspan.w` into the SGB directory. Invoke `ctangle` on it to obtain the `grayspan.c`.

> You may need to use a text editor to replace all occurrences of word "verbose" in `grayspan.c` with something else ("overbose" or something). This is because `gb_graph.h` now defines a global variable named "verbose". However, if everything is done as described hereby, this should not be necessary.

Invoke

```
gcc -m32 -o grayspan grayspan.c gb_graph.c gb_save.c gb_io.c
```

You will get a certain deal of non-critical warnings (easy to fix if you care) and a working "grayspan" program.

Comment: thanks for the info on the latest version of the pseudo code converter for C. and especially on the detail about the tool/header files defining `verbose`

Comment: Thanks you,yes that worked.  I also needed to 'sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386' [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498237/compile-program-for-32bit-on-64bit-linux-os-causes-fatal-error]

Comment: The program was clearly developed for 32b platform, so working 32b setup is implied.