# Shellcode ends in seg fault

Tags: c, assembly, shellcode

I tried to run the second example (print 'hello') described at this tutorial:
http://www.vividmachines.com/shellcode/shellcode.html.

This is my C code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

char code[] = "\xeb\x19\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xd2\x31\xc9\xb0\x04\xb3\x01\x59\xb2\x05\xcd"\
              "\x80\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80\xe8\xe2\xff\xff\xff\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f";

int main() {
    void *buf;
    buf = mmap (0,sizeof(code),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,
                MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0);
    memcpy (buf, code, sizeof(code));
    int (*func)() = (int (*)()) buf;
    func ();
    return 0;
}
```

The code variable at the beginning is the code of the assembly file:

```
[SECTION .text]

global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov dl, 5
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80

msg:    db 'hello'
```

When I compile and run just the asm file, it works good (prints 'hello').
But when I compile and run the C code above, it just prints nothing.

Can someone explain me why is that?

Comment: `The code variable at the beginning is the code of the assembly file:` - No, the opcodes used as the shell code are different. That is also shown in the linked page - they do additional stuff like clearing out registers (obviously this code will then not run as a standalone application, mainly due to the stack setup). But, the main question is: how do you compile the C code? Which system are you using - is that a 64 bit architecture? `int 0x80` only works in x86 (32 bit) code.

Comment: If I compile the C code with `gcc -m32 -o shell -Wall -pedantic shell.c` on an `x86_64` system, it properly prints "hello"

Comment: @Andreas When I compile as you do I got:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:25:0,
                 from shellcodetest.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:374:25: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <sys/cdefs.h>

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for the correction and the explanation about the opcodes. 
I'm using 64-bit architecture

Comment: Then you indeed need to compile with `-m32`. The compile error you get is most likely caused by the missing 32 bit runtime libraries - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498237/compile-program-for-32bit-on-64bit-linux-os-causes-fatal-error. Which Linux system are you using?

Comment: @Andreas I use kali, but the link you gave me was really helpful and now it works. Thank you!