# What does allocating memory of size char * do?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocation

```
char    *str;
str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
```

This code allocates 5 consecutive slots of memory to the variable `str`, which is of type `char *`.

```
char    *str;
str = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 5);
```

This is supposed to allocate 5 times the memory of an array of char. But since an array of char has no size until we declare it, what does this statement actually do?

Comment: the * says pointer not array. It allocate a block of 5 pointer to chars

Comment: `char *` is itself a data type (pointer-to-char), so the second statement allocates a memory block to store 5 char-pointers.

Comment: BTW, on my system (Linux/x86-64) `sizeof(char*)` is 8 (like the size of any pointer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code

```
char **str = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 5);
```

allocates memory for *5*-consecutive elements of type `char *`, i.e.: *pointer to char*.

You could then allocate *N*-consecutive elements of type `char` and assign their addresses to these pointers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   str[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * N));
```

Comment: if it is confusing please explain why

Answer (score 5):

For the first part

> *This code allocates 5 "consecutive slots of memory" to the variable `str`, which is of type `char *`.*

No, not really. To be exact, in case it is successful, it returns a pointer to a memory block large enough to hold 5 `char`s, that's the size supplied to `malloc()`. In `C`, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`, so that's 5 bytes.

Related, `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.4

> The `malloc()` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by `size` and
>   whose value is indeterminate.

So, there's no "consecutive block" as such, it's a memory region (*space for "an" object*) with specified size.

In later case, the size is for `char *`, a pointer. depending on your environment, the amount of bytes will be `5 * sizeof (char *)`, where `sizeof(char *)` can be either 4 or 8 or anything else.

**Note**, both the cases, the returned pointer is of type `void *`.

---

***Also Note this***

The datatype, used in supplying the size in `malloc()` argument has no attachment or influence on the returned pointer, it is **solely** used for calculation of the `size` to be passed to `malloc()`.

For example, if it so happens that for a certain platform, `sizeof(int)` === `sizeof(float)`, then, we can write

```
    int *intPtr = malloc(sizeof *fltPtr);   //int pointer
    float *fltPtr = malloc(sizeof *intPtr); // float pointer
```

and considering success, we can make use of both the pointers flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

```
char    *str;
str = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 5);
```

It allocates enough memory to store 5 pointers to char (5 addresses). It is not allocating memory to store arrays, but only their addresses

Answer (score 1):

The second part actually allocates 5 times a pointer of char, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%u\n", sizeof(char *));
}
```

If you compile the above code in 32-bit environment, this code will print 4. In 64-bit environment, this code will print 8. (You can test this by yourself on an 64-bit environment by following the steps described below at **How to test**.)

So based on your environment, `char *str = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 5);` allocates `20` or `40` bytes of memory which is pointed by `str`. So if you are planning to store a c-type-string in `str`, you'll be able to store `19` or `39` characters.

---

### How to test

I'm on **64-bit** Ubuntu 14.04. On 64-bit environment you can test the above sample code with following compiler options.

```
$ gcc -m32 -o out32 main.c
$ ./out32
4
$ gcc -o out64 main.c
$ ./out64
8
```

If you get error saying `sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory` then install following packges.

```
$ sudo apt install libx32gcc-4.8-dev
$ sudo apt install libc6-dev-i386
```

(Got required packge names from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23499492/7724939))